# G Suite private listing modification

Tags: marketplace, google-workspace

I created a private listing on G Suite Market place and all worked like charm.

Now, I need to change the landing page URL (domain remains the same) for which I modified it in manifest file which is not getting reflected.

So the question is:
- Is there any other entry/change I need to make?
- Or do I need to ask the administrator to uninstall and re-install the widget from the market place which will reflect the changes?

Thanks in advance!